# Expresión regular para resultados 'diferentes a ...'

Tags: linux, regex, bash, csv

Estoy intentando realizar una expresión regular que encuentre todas los registros que sean diferentes a `other` (en mi caso).

He visto esta expresión: `other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+)` pero al parecer solo es valida en ciertos lenguajes, y en mi caso, `bash` no es valido.

La expresión que uso actualmente es esta:

```
(GP?|MS?),(F?|M?),(1[5-8]),(U?|R?),[a-zA-Z0-9]*,(A?|T?),[1-4],[0-4],other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+),other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+),[a-z]*,[a-z]*,[1-4],[1-4],[0-4],(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),[1-5],[1-5],[1-5],[4-5],[1-5],[1-5],[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*
```

Pero me trae todos los registros contengan o no `other` en esa columna. **Es un regex para un `.csv`**.

¿Como puedo transformar `,other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+),other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+),` para que me devuelva todos los valores diferentes a `other`, pero en **bash**?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cadenas que cumplan y otras que no?

Answer (score 0):

No es la solución ideal, pero es una alternativa para conseguir lo que quieres. Las negaciones en expresiones regulares no son algo sencillo.

No se si estás usando para leer el archivo el comando [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) o uno del estilo.

Yo te diría que usaras la expresión regular que tienes cambiando la condición  `other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+)` por, por ejemplo, `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` , y con la salida, a través de un [pipe](https://www.linuxito.com/gnu-linux/nivel-basico/1287-named-pipes-en-linux), utilizaras [awk](http://www.sromero.org/wiki/linux/aplicaciones/uso_de_awk) para obtener los resultados que quieres.

Por lo que veo en tu expresión regular, las columnas 9 y 10 son las que tienen que tener un valor diferente a "other", por lo que el comando completo sería algo así (suponiendo que tu archivo se llamara test.csv):

```
grep -E '<tu expresion regular cambiando los other(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+) por [a-zA-Z0-9]*>' test.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $9!="other" && $10!="other" { print $0}'
```

Con esto la salida te devolvería las filas que no tienen el texto "other" en esas columnas, con el filtrado previo de la expresión regular del comando grep.

Como explicación rápida, lo que hace este comando es evaluar por columnas. Le estamos diciendo que el separador de campos `FS` son comas, y que si la columna 9 y la 10 tienen un texto diferente a "other" que imprima la línea.

Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda